# Alternatives to LinkedBlockingDeque?

Tags: java

I've a Java program that runs on multiple threads. One of the threads wait for data from another thread and processes it. I used `LinkedBlockingDeque` to implement it, such that the thread will block until data is available in the queue.

However, the server I'm running on only has Java SE 5, a version that does not have this particular class. Are there any alternatives to this?

Comment: Have you considered implementing it yourself?

Comment: Can you not use `LinkedBlockingQueue` instead of `LinkedBlockingDequeue`?

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja How should I do that?

Comment: @JonSkeet Doesn't `LinkedBlockingQueue` block only on insertion and not on removal? How should that work out?

Comment: You could implement your own *Producer-Consumer* pattern. check it in  [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)

Comment: The simplest way I would think is to download jdk 1.7 (or later) and seeing how java implements it.

Comment: @mushroom look at the source code for `LinkedBlockingDequeue`

Comment: the best approach would be to implement it on your own. see the source code  here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.java

Comment: @mushroom: I don't see any evidence of that. It implements `BlockingQueue`, and has `take()` and `poll` methods... what makes you think it's only blocking in one way?

Comment: @JavaBond: That sounds like a bad idea to me. Threading can be very subtle indeed; it's possible that the source of `LinkedBlockingDequeue` will depend on some particular aspects of other classes. I don't think the OP needs to implement anything here.

Comment: As a side-note: if the server is only running Java 1.5, that may well mean that it has significant security vulnerabilities. I would strongly urge you to start trying to get it upgraded.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hmm. That's true, I was under the impression that `BlockingQueue` only does it one way. On the other hand, the server is not under my administrative control.

Comment: @mushroom: Just because you can't perform the update yourself doesn't mean you can't start agitating for it - or plan to move somewhere else. What are you going to do if you find there *is* a significant security hole which is being exploited?

Comment: @JonSkeet Agreed but since `LinkedBlockingDequeue` extends `AbstractQueue` which is available in Java 5 and implements `BlockingDeque` which OP can introduce of his own there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @JavaBond: "There shouldn't be an issue" doesn't sound like a good reason to start copying code with potentially *very* subtle semantics around the memory model. Even though all the other classes that `LinkedBlockingDequeue` uses may exist, one particular implementation may end up relying on some aspects of other class implementation details. This is especially pointless when `LinkedBlockingQueue` can do the job already.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, Jon, for the best answer and simplest solution. Couldn't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For requirements you described you can use LinkedBlockingQueue available in Java 5

Answer (score 0):

You can use [backports](http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net/):

> The ambition of this project is to provide a concurrency library that
>   works with uncompromised performance on all Java platforms currently
>   in use, allowing development of fully portable concurrent
>   applications. More precisely, the traget scope is Java 1.3 and above,
>   and some limited support if offered for Java 1.2.